# What does "thousands of hundreds of people" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, numbers

What the title says. How many people are there when ***a larger quantity** (thousands)* is followed by a ***smaller quantity** (hundreds)*. **Is this even grammatical?**

**I can understand "hundreds of thousands", though**; it means *"many hundred thousands (100 000)"*, which can be 200k, 300k, 400k, etc. But using "*many thousand hundreds"* as a definition for *"thousands of hundreds"* just doesn't seem right to me. Help?

Comment: Where did you read "many thousand hundred..."?

Comment: I too am interested where you read this obviously mangled prose, and also why you think it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be a normal expression.  I suppose if the items could be naturally grouped into divisions of about 100:

> The men form teams, and many thousands of hundreds of men begin to dig the fields.  (The implication is that each team has about 100 men in it)

Otherwise it is "smaller number first".

Comment: In that case I think we would be more likely to say "Thousands of hundred-man teams..."